# Take mobile screenshots with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I'm building a Chrome extension that takes a screenshot of the user's active tab. I want to take both desktop and mobile screenshots.

For Desktop screenshot, I use the the `chrome.tabCapture` API functions and capture the content of the currently active tab.

How can I take a **screenshot for mobile or custom dimensions**?

Comment: Are you saying you want this to work on a mobile device, or that you want the user's screen to be adjusted to mobile dimensions and then another screenshot taken?

Comment: I want to adjust the user screen to mobile dimensions and then take another screenshot. And if this process will be visible to the end-user or can be hidden as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chrome.windows.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update) to force a resize. The received `updateInfo` object should have the `width` and `height` you wish to use. (there is no standard 'mobile' size).

You'd probably want to also -

1. Store the pre-resize dimensions and restore to it later. You can do it with [chrome.windows.getCurrent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getCurrent), and inspect the returned `Window` for width and height.
2. Take care to account for toolbars and window margins, to get as
   close as you can to emulating true mobile experience.